# python - if statement return wrong value

Tags: python

I used the followng code to trigger IF statement based on the value of row[0]  my problem is always IF statement give me wrong output even if the value is greater than 0 its keep printing NO FAILURE .

```
conn = psycopg2.connect(conn_string)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select count(*) as result from events_log where match_event_timestamp  > (NOW() - INTERVAL '147 hours');")
        row = cursor.fetchone()
        cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) AS result FROM events_log  WHERE status = 'FAILURE' AND match_event_timestamp  > (NOW() - INTERVAL '24 hours');")
        row += cursor.fetchone()
        logger.info("Number of Events in last 24hr : %s ; Number of Event FAILURE  in last 24h: %s" % (row[0],row[1]))
        output = { 'api_key':'jhfsdf', 'data': { 'item' : [
                        {'text': 'Today ', 'value': row[0]},
                        {'text': 'Current Month ', 'value': row[1]}
                    ] } }

        if row[0] > '0':
                print('FAILURE')
        else:
                print("NO FAILURE")
```

what did i missed in IF statement here ?

Comment: You mean greater than `0` not `'0'` right?

Comment: i dont know what row[0] contains... but what happens if you convert them to int before evaluating the condition of the if/else ? like  `if int(row[0]) > 0:`

Comment: fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'0'` is a string use `0`. Like this:

```
if( row[0] > 0 ):
   ...
```

Otherwise you get this:

```
TypeError: unorderable types: int() > str()
```

which means you may not compare an `int` to a `string`.